# I have a table and the strings in that table should be split as shown in the description

Tags: sql-server

Table is

```
create table mtest
(
     id int,
     strval varchar(150),
     strval1 varchar(150)
)

insert into mtest 
values (1, 'a b c d', 'xxyyzzaa')

insert into mtest 
values(2, 'e f', 'ccdd')

insert into mtest 
values(3, 'g h i', 'llmmnn')

insert into mtest 
values(4, 'j', 'kk')
```

Answer should be

```
1 xx
1 yy
1 zz
1 aa
2 cc
2 dd....
```

Comment: which description?

Comment: So, is `strval` relevant in any way? Is this just "take each pair of letters from `strval1` and make a new row from them"?

Comment: It is really not clear what you want.  For example, you could implement by returning pairs of two characters (1 and 2, 3 and 4 etc) from strval1 and ignore strval.  Or you could return pairs of adjacent letters which are the same from both strval and strval1. Also what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
DECLARE @mtest TABLE (Id int, strval VARCHAR(150), strval1 VARCHAR(150))
INSERT INTO @mtest 
VALUES
(1,'a b c d','xxyyzzaa'),
(2,'e f','ccdd'),
(3,'g h i','llmmnn'),
(4,'j','kk')

DECLARE @MaxLength INT = (SELECT MAX(LEN(strval1)) FROM @mtest)

;WITH CTE (RowId)
AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS RowId
    UNION ALL
    SELECT RowId + 2 AS Id
    FROM CTE
    WHERE
        RowId < @MaxLength 
)

SELECT
    M.Id,
    M.strval1,          
    SUBSTRING(strval1, C.RowId, 2) AS Result
FROM
    @mtest M CROSS JOIN 
    CTE C
WHERE
    SUBSTRING(strval1, C.RowId, 2) != ''
ORDER BY M.Id
```

Result:

```
Id      strval1      Result     
------- ------------ ------
1       xxyyzzaa     xx
1       xxyyzzaa     yy
1       xxyyzzaa     zz
1       xxyyzzaa     aa
2       ccdd         dd
2       ccdd         cc
3       llmmnn       ll
3       llmmnn       mm
3       llmmnn       nn
4       kk           kk
```